# How can I check if all the rows in DataGridView is not null?

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, datagridview

I had this problem quite a while.

What I planned to do is that if all of the `cell[0]` has value, it will trigger an event. If there is `null`, it'll change the value of the `TextBox`.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == null)
        {
            textbox.Text = "null";
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No null");
        }
    }
```

But whats happening here is for example I have 3 rows in `DataGridView`, if the first row is not null it will lunch the `MessageBox`. I want the `MessageBox` to be triggered when all of the row's cells are not null.

Comment: where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool anyNull = false;
for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == null)
    {
        textbox.Text = "null";
        anyNull = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!anyNull)
    MessageBox.Show("");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ and [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(c => c.Cells[0].Value?.ToString() == null))
{
    textbox.Text = "null";
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No null"); 
}
```

Also it would be better to use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
     .Any(c => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Cells[0].Value?.ToString())))
```

Comment: for me `c => c.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` bombs with a `System.NullReferenceException` that I fixed with `c => c.Cells[0].Value`

Comment: @blaze_125 Or using *Null-conditional* (`?.`) Operator like this `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.Cells[0].Value?.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
       if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == null)
       {
            textbox.Text = "null";
            break;
       } 
 }
if(textbox.Text != "null")
{ 
     MessageBox.Show("No null"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the code below, but it is not recommend to use `goto`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == null)
        {
            textbox.Text = "null";
            goto a;
        }

    }

    a:  MessageBox.Show("Null");
```

Comment: xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: Why not use `break`?

Comment: sry, not even a c# beginner, but it is easier for me to understand when there is not too many goto xD

Comment: Why would you suggest this? If you find a null set the text as null and show a messagebox that says no nulls?